# How can I vertically center text within my button element?

Tags: html, css

I've created a button element, and am having a difficult time getting the text vertically centered. The margin and padding appear to not be an issue. I feel like I'm missing something straightforward, or not fully understanding how the element is being rendered.

[button with vertically uncentered text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2MBh.png)

[close-up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdM6r.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/morcant/tovp1s6c/1/

I've tried centering the element with `display: inline-flex; align-items: center;`, and adjusting the line-height value. Changing the line height appears to increase the height of the line, but doesn't seem to help with vertically centering the text.

I'm using Firefox and Windows 10, with the [Simple CSS framework](https://simplecss.org/).

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the jsfiddle doesn't include the button and the text within the button in the image seems to be vertically centered within the the button?

Comment: Remember that text could include some characters with descenders, like g, and some taller characters, eg X in this typeface. What would you want to happen if the text were contacting?

Comment: @DibsyJr the jsfiddle does seem to contain the button.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and feedback - I'll make sure to post a minimal reproducible example next time!

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell that it isn't centered, unless you use the browser dev tools to inspect the element. The text within the button element is ever so slightly off-centered downwards. The height of the line appears to be slightly larger than the height of the text, with the text vertically aligned to the bottom. I suppose I would like to understand why it's being rendered this way, to figure out the best solution to address it. Thanks!

Comment: That's a great point @AHaworth , which I hadn't considered. However, I don't think it'll be an issue in this instance, as long as I keep the text as `contact` in all lowercase

Comment: So you want that text in that font to ‘optically’ seem centred - ie the top of the tallest character represented to be the same distance from the top border as the lowest point of any character there is from the bottom border. The amount you will have to adjust will be entirely dependant on the font in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend and append some HTML content before/after the contact button and specify their height in percentage:

```css
html > body > header {
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.contact > div {
  height: 35%;
}

header > ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

header > ul.nav li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header > ul.nav .nav-title-container {
    text-align: left;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

header > ul.nav .nav-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

header > ul.nav .nav-title a {
    color: var(--code);
}

header > ul.nav .nav-subtitle {
    margin-bottom: .25rem;
    margin-top: .25rem;
}

header > ul.nav .contact {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

header > ul.nav .contact button {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--code);
    border: 1px solid var(--code);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>First Last</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.simplecss.org/simple.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-title-container">
                <h1 class="nav-title"><a href="/index.html">First Last</a></h1>
                <h4 class="nav-subtitle">Title</h4>
                <h4 class="nav-subtitle">Subtitle</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="contact">
                <div>
                </div>
                <a href="/contact.html"><button>contact</button></a>
                <div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear - I want the text inside the button vertically centered, not the button element itself. Thanks for your time!